# How to do communication between started service and Intent Service

Tags: android

I would like to know what is the best way to perform communication between Started service and an IntentService.

I have a service which is listening to Step Detector events, when StepsCount reaches to a certain number (I unregistered Step Detector ) and start an Intent service this intent service listens to Accelerometer Sensor and and record accelerometer data, and perform activity recognition, Once this activity recognition process is finished I want to pass a message to my Started Service so that it can again start listening to step detector.

**Currently I am using broadcast receiver to send broadcast from Intent Service after finishing the task and register. Are there some other and better alternatives ? please suggest.**

Comment: just start it again?

Answer (score 0):

You can give it a try to Otto and EventBus libraries.

Otto : http://square.github.io/otto/
EventBus : https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus